# Trying to push data to an empty array not working as expected when I made a new class

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, oop

So I am trying to push the values of the instantiated contestant object into an empty array as seen in the submitForm function inside my ManageContestant class. I logged the array to my console to see if there were any present values, but it seems it is just an empty instance of a contestant object with no values. It initially worked when my code was separate and not placed inside the newly created ManageContestant class I created.

However, I made this change because I read that practicing creating variables in the global space is not recommended? and it just did not seem right to me, so I would rather prefer the empty array inside my ManageContestant class or if there would be any other suggestions anyone could recommend to create better code. I will provide the working code without the ManageContestant class for a better context as well as the non-working code.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-napier-3yntd?file=/app.js)

**Console values:**

[Sucessfully pushing contestants in the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxlZn.png)

[No object data showing when I click the arrow using the ManageContestant class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nefC.png)

**Working Code no ManageContestant class**

```
class Contestant {
  constructor(name, age, location, song, link){
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
      this.location = location;
      this.song = song;
      this.link = link;
  }

}

const contestantDataArray =[];

document.querySelector(".regoForm").addEventListener('submit', 
function(e){


// Instantiate Contestant - create an instance

   // Get values from contestant rego form
const name = document.querySelector("#contName").value,
age = document.querySelector("#contAge").value,
location = document.querySelector("#contLocation").value,
song = document.querySelector("#song").value,
link = document.querySelector("#link").value;
const contestant = new Contestant(name, age, location, song, link);

contestantDataArray.push(contestant);

Store.addContestant(contestant);

}

  e.preventDefault();
  
});
```

**Code to fix using the ManageContestant class**

```
class Contestant {
    constructor(name, age, location, song, link){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.location = location;
        this.song = song;
        this.link = link;
    }

}

class ManageContestant{
    constructor(){
         // pass the data in the profileIterator function
         this.contestantDataArray = [];
        this.events();
    }



//Events
events() {
    // Create event for next button
    document.querySelector(".regoForm").addEventListener('submit', () => this.submitForm())
}


//Methods

submitForm(){

let array = this.contestantDataArray;
 
   
     // Add contestant to list
 ui.addContestantToList(contestant);
 
// THE PROBLEM IS HERE, THE ARRAY IS NOT GETTIN ANY VALUES OF THE CONTESTANT OBJECT BEING PUSHED

 array.push(contestant);
 
 
 Store.addContestant(contestant);
 
     
 };
}
```

Comment: Could you create a http://codesandbox.io/ and share? Also, would be great if you mention the problem via code comments. Currently it's not clear from where the values of those variables `name`, `age` etc. are coming from.

Comment: @abdul-wahab ty for your response ! I have added the code where the data of name and age is coming from as well as commented where the problem is in the code, here is the link to the codesandbox for the full code https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-napier-3yntd?file=/app.js